# codename one signatueComponent image upload

Tags: java, php, codenameone, multipart

i have be trying to upload the signature captured from the codename one signature to my php server.the problem is that the image uploaded is a black image.Below is my code.how can i fix this

```
SignatureComponent sig = new SignatureComponent();
sig.addActionListener((evt)-> {
try{
img = sig.getSignatureImage();
}catch(Exception ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
      }
// Now we can do whatever we want with the image of this signature.
});
Button sv = new Button("save");
sv.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             try {


                Label it = new Label();
                it.setIcon(img);
                orderHome.add(it);

                 ImageIO imgIO= ImageIO.getImageIO();
                 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 imgIO.save(img, out,ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1);
                 byte[] ba = out.toByteArray();
                 MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
                 String url = Global.url1 + "upload_photo.php";

                 request.setUrl(url);


                     request.addData("file",ba,"image/jpeg");
                  request.addArgument("order_id", order_id);
                request.addArgument("customer_id", customer_id);

                 NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
```

and the php code

```
[![image uploaded][1]][1]
<?php
@SESSION_START();
require_once("../includes/functions.php");
$target_path="../uploads/";
$customer_id=$_REQUEST['customer_id'];
$order_id=$_REQUEST['order_id'];
$uid = uniqid();
$file =$uid.".jpg";
$sucess=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_path.$file);
```

[image: image uploaded to server]
[image: screenshot of the simulator]

the black img is the file which is uploaded to the server.the other shows the screenshot of the running app.i would like to upload the signature as shown in the screenshot

Comment: the black img is the file which is uploaded to the server.the other shows the screenshot of the running app.i would like to upload the signature as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Does `orderHome` contain a valid image after this process completes when you add a label to it? I noticed you didn't revalidate after the add so it might not show. In the debugger does the array look like it has the right image content? If you save it to a file does it contain valid data?

Comment: the image shows when i add it to the label in the orderHome form.the array when viewed using the network manager shows that it contains some image content ( though am not sure if its the right image content).the problem is when the image is save to file.it shows the black image that i added above

Comment: Try using FORMAT_PNG just to test something... Did this only happen on the simulator or did you try a device too?

Comment: FORMAT_PNG seems to do the trick.its working perfectly now.thank you..i would also like a bit of explanation as to why FORMAT_JPEG isnt working

Answer (score 1):

The signature generates a translucent image. JavaSE has some issues with saving translucent images as JPEGs and thus PNG works well. Another alternative would be to create an opaque image and save that as a JPEG e.g.:

```
Image myImage = Image.create(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
myImage.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

The new `myImage` will be opaque with the white color background.